# React Native Picker: Show different item lists

Tags: react-native, react-native-picker-select

I am learning to use React Native Picker. For now, as an example, I have added two `user type`: *Freelancer*, and *Client*.

I want to show different `picker item` depending on the `user type` selected. At the moment, my app shows all the items regardless of the `user type` selected.

For example: If the user selects `user type` *Freelancer*, I want to show `picker item` to be *Freelancer 1* and *Freelancer 2*.

And, if user selects `user type` *Client*, I want to show `picker item` to be *Client 1* and *Client 2*.

I am new with this so any help will be highly appreciated.

**Code snippet provided below:**

```
export default class FrTopUpScreen extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            userType: '',
            clientName: '',
            freelancerName: '',
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                    <Text style={styles.titleStyle}>User Type</Text>
                    <View style={styles.pickerStyle}>
                        {<Picker
                            mode='dropdown'
                            selectedValue={this.state.userType}
                            onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
                                this.setState({ userType: itemValue })
                            }>
                            <Picker.Item label="Select User Type" value="" />
                            <Picker.Item label="Freelancer" value="Freelancer" />
                            <Picker.Item label="Client" value="Client" />
                        </Picker>}
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                    <Text style={styles.titleStyle}>Name</Text>
                    <View style={styles.pickerStyle}>
                        <Picker
                            mode='dropdown'
                            selectedValue={this.state.name}
                            onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
                                this.setState({ name: itemValue })
                            }>
                            <Picker.Item label="Please Select" value="" />
                            <Picker.Item label="Freelancer 1" value="Freelancer 1" />
                            <Picker.Item label="Freelancer 2" value="Freelancer 2" />
                            <Picker.Item label="Client 1" value="Client 1" />
                            <Picker.Item label="Client 2" value="Client 2" />
                        </Picker>
                    </View>
                </View>
        );
    };
};
```

Comment: You will have to use multiple pickers for doing so

Comment: I just want to show different `name` picker list depending on the `user type` selected. In this case, if `user type` is `Freelancer` then I want to show the picker with `Freelancer 1` and `Freelancer 2`. And, if the `user type` is `Client` then I want to show the picker with `Client 1` and `Client 2`. Regarding multiple pickers, I am not sure about that.

Comment: So you want to show different option in same picker when user selects one?

Comment: Yes. Something like that, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this :

```
var pickerItems = ["Freelancer","Client"];
var freelancer =["Freelancer1","Freelancer2"];
var client =["Client1","Client2"];

<Picker
    style={{your_style}}
    mode="dropdown"
    selectedValue={this.state.selected}
    onValueChange={()=>{
     if(selectedValue == Freelancer)
     {
         this.setState({
              pickerItems=this.state.freelancer
         });
     }
     else{
         this.setState({
              pickerItems=this.state.client
         });
     }
   }}>
    {pickerItems.map((item, index) => {
        return (<Picker.Item label={item} value={index} key={index}/>) 
    })}
</Picker>
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work sorry. I was getting multiple errors. Right now it would be too hectic to post the errors here at the moment. But thanks for the suggestion.